# org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBBlob to File

Tags: java, swing, casting, firebird, jaybird

I need  to open to user a PDF file which is being saved as a Blob on the firebird database.
I tried:

```
pdf = (File) res.getBlob("blob");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdf);
```

But it does not let me cast blob to file.
What would be the ideal way of doing this ?

Comment: You can't just cast objects to random objects of a totally different type in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the blob's `getBinaryStream()` method to read the blob, and write the stream to a `File` created via `createTempFile()`. You can then `open()` the resulting `File`.

Comment: how do I write to the file created ?

Comment: I'd look at `new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f))` where `f` is the `File`.

Comment: @VitorHugo Look at the Java Tutorial on byte streams (and related I/O tutorials): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html